# How to remove rows if factor in column A matches factor in column B

Tags: r, dataframe, int, levels

I have a dataframe with 9 million rows and 3 variables. The 3 variables are Origin (factor w/ 46 levels), Destination (factor w/ 46 levels), and Throughput (int).

A simplified version of my dataframe looks like this:
https://ibb.co/0p7g37B

I want to remove the rows where Origin is equal to Destination (eg. 12th = 12th or 16th=16th)

I want my output to look like this:
https://ibb.co/k6h7qc2

DATA:

```
df <- structure(list(Origin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
  ), .Label = c("12th", "16th"), class = "factor"), Destination = structure(c(1L, 
  1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("12th", "16th", "CIVC", "COLS", 
  "FTVL"), class = "factor"), Throughput = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
  1L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Using images means that anyone who wants to use the data to test their solution must retype it all.  Please provide the data in text form by showing the output of `dput(X)` in the question where `X` is the input object.  To show it in the question indent each line by 4 spaces and SO will automatically format it for you.

Comment: maybe `dplyr::anti_join` https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-spark-in-r-using-sparklyr/tools-of-the-trade-advanced-dplyr-usage?ex=12 ?

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks
dput(    | Origin | Destination | Throughput |
    -------------------------------------
    |   12th |    12th     |     1      | 
    |   12th |    12th     |     2      | 
    |   12th |    COLS     |     1      | 
    |   12th |    COLS     |     4      |
    |   16th |    16th     |     2      |
    |   16th |    CIVC     |     1      |
    |   16th |    FTVL     |     7      |)

Comment: @OTA `library(dplyr);df %>% mutate_at(vars("Origin", "Destination"), list(as.character)) %>% filter(Origin!=Destination)`, but since you have 9M rows I'd have a look at `data.table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dummy variable having string values 1 and 0. 1 in case, origin and destination values are same  else 0. Then, you can do filter out rows where you have string value 0 in newly created dummy variable.do it in way given below:

```
data = read.csv("filepath of csv file.csv")
data$newdummy = ifelse(data$Origin == data$Destination, '1' ,'0')
data1 <- data[data$newdummy == '0',]
```

Later, you can drop the column wherein you created dummy values -

```
data1 <- data1[-4]
```

if the position of new dummy column is 3rd.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both Bruno"s and Nitesh"s answers produce desired output but I think there is no need for an extra mutate statement. You can directly filter your results:

```
df <- df %>% filter(Origin != Destination)
```

One more thing: To be able to compare two factor variables they should have same levels. You should edit levels of origin or destination variable in a way that both of them have same levels.

Comment: Yeap, this is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~Origin,~Destination,~Throughput,
             "12th","12th",1,
             "12th","12th",2,
             "12th","COLS",1,
             "12th","COLS",4,
             "16th","16th",2,
             "16th","CIVC",1,
             "16th","FTVL",7)

df %>%
  mutate(is_equal = if_else(Origin == Destination,
                                 TRUE,
                                 FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(is_equal == FALSE) %>% 
  select(-is_equal)
```